# Is $x^\alpha \sin(1/x^\beta)$ an anti-derivative on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Define $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ as
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^\alpha  \sin(1/x^\beta) &\text{if }0 < x \leq 1\\
0 & \text{if } x = 0 \end{cases}$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive real numbers.
If $0 < \alpha - \beta \leq 1$, then the derivative of $f$ at 0 is not defined. However, $f'$ is well-defined on $(0,1]$ and $\int_0^1 |f'| < \infty$. Is it still valid to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to write
$$
f(x) = \int_0^x f'
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x > y > 0$, we have $\int_{y}^x f'(t)\; dt = f(x) - f(y)$.  Since $\lim_{y \to 0+} f(y) = 0$, $\int_0^x f'(t)\; dt = f(x)$ as an improper Riemann integral.